# Xcode 5.1 crash when changing the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode5.1

Xcode 5.1 has been a pain in the ass ever since I installed it.

When I change the simulator in Xcode 5.1, it just crashes. No error messages whatsoever. I removed it and re-installed it but the problem still persists.

Has anyone experienced this? Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

I reported the issue to Apple. But I need a workaround for the time being.

Update:

Below is the crash log. And here's the detailed [report](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EgufQreA).

[image]

Comment: Check `Console` for a log. Are you using genuine Mac and OS X ?

Comment: Yes. All original. Btw I solved the problem. I performed a clean uninstall. Removed all the settings/cache and re-installed it again. [This](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2008/Sep/msg00444.html) article helped. Now the issue is gone :)

Comment: Okay, its crashing again. Argh! @A-Live Can you please tell me how to check for a log? Do you mean the console in Xcode?

Comment: It is a standard app under `/Applications/Utilities`, most of the apps write their logs there. Did you try to install any Xcode components between it worked and started to crash ?

Comment: @A-Live I updated my question with the crash log info.

Comment: Quit Xcode and clean out all simulators and the derived data folder by hand.

Comment: Your [Polychromatic](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/Polychromatic) plugin is the issue. I'd recommend to remove it and create an issue record on Github with attached log file.

Comment: @matt Removed all the simulators and data and re-installed Xcode. A-Live was right. It had something to do with a plugin I had installed.

Comment: @A-Live I removed the problematic Polychromatic and now it appears to be working properly. Thank you so much! :) May I ask how you found out that it was the cause? I have zero knowledge in decrypting crash logs.

Comment: @A-Live Also someone has already opened an [issue](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/Polychromatic/issues/14) recently and a workaround has been posted too. But I guess I'll wait until it's fixed for good.

Comment: @Isuru, some of the backtrace lines leaded to `~/Downloads/Polychromatic-master/` - obviously not a part of Xcode installation, then I googled for the project source and the puzzle was done. The fact that you built it locally actually helped a lot.

Comment: @A-Live I see. Thanks :) If you can post it as an answer, I can accept it.